# Ошибка при работе с распределенным кешированием

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

При работе с [распределенным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1) кешем в ASP.NET CORE 3.1, возникает ошибка, что не установлено средство `sql-cache`, хотя на самом деле оно установленно, кто нибудь встречался с данной проблемой, как решали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Знаю, что есть вот такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362898/creating-asp-net-core-sql-cache-table), но мне оно не помогло, ошибка осталась

Comment: Скорее всего разница в версиях. У вас рантайм 3.1 установлен? Почему ткой старый .NET используете? Это же сервер, зачем на нем старье держать?

Comment: @aepot да, нам приходится использовать ASP.NET Core 3.1 (я знаю что есть 6 версия)
тем не менее в офицальной документации есть пункт, что данный средство работает во всех Core начиная с 2ого

Comment: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sql-cache --version 3.1.0